# How can I prevent autologout of user in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, session-cookies, logout

When the user uses my symfony application, then after a couple of minutes the user is automatically logged out, while he is working with the application. To prevent that I changed in

config/packages/framework.yaml

```
framework:    
   session:
   cookie_lifetime: 86400
   gc_maxlifetime: 1800
```

This means the cookie lifetime is set to 24 hours. So I expect the user will only be logged out when he closes the browser. But in reality he is still automatically logged out after half in hour or so. What other options can I try?

Comment: what is the `set-cookie` header in the response? what expiration does the browser shows for the cookie?

Comment: Have a look to https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection

Comment: @the_nuts what do you mean exactly be set cookie header?

Comment: @Mcsky You mean I should add `gc_probability: null`

Comment: Did you try to unset `gc_maxlifetime` ? It [seem](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) that PHP clear the session after this time. Moreover it's 30 minutes lifetime like your logged out problem. You should definitively **don't** set gc_probability  to null otherwise PHP won't ever clean your "dead" session and your server will be lack of disk space after a time. It can be worth it to have a look to your `php.ini` configuration values also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to unset gc_maxlifetime ? It [seem](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) that PHP clear the session after this time. Moreover it's 30 minutes lifetime like your logged out problem.

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 86400
```

You should definitively don't set `gc_probability` to null otherwise PHP won't ever clean your "dead" session and your server will be lack of disk space after a time.

Also it can be worth it to have a look to your `php.ini` configuration values because PHP will take them if they aren't specifid in Symfony configuration.

In other words Symfony override your PHP configuration if you specify somes configurations ([there is a list of them](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.4/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php#L100) )

Comment: oh ok, I understand, so you mean just remove this line `gc_maxlifetime: 1800`

Comment: Yep that's all, let me know if it fix :) Also have a look to your `.ini session configuration` just in case